# How to write 3 lists to 6 columns with Python3 and SQlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, python-3.x, executemany

I need to write 3 lists containing value pairs into 6 columns with sqlite3.

```
my_list = ['a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4']
my_list2 = ['e','5','f','6','g','7','h','8']
my_list3 = ['i','9','j','10','k','11','l','12']
```

like so:

```
| a | 1 | e | 5 | i | 9 |
| b | 2 | f | 6 | j | 10|
| c | 3 | g | 7 | k | 11|
| d | 4 | h | 8 | l | 12|
```

I need the each pair to be inserted into the .db next to each other. I can do this utilizing a pairwise function and execute many for a single list.

The pairwise function:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    return zip(iterable, iterable)
```

The execute many code that works for one list:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO mytable(column1, column2) VALUES (?,?)', pairwise(my_list))
connection.commit()
```

Whenever I try to pass the other lists at the same time:

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO mytable(column1, column2, column3, column4, column4, column6) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',pairwise(my_list),pairwise(my_list2),pairwise(my_list3))
conn.commit()
```

I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`executemany()` can take **an** iterator of sequences (such as tuples) for the arguments, but when you write

```
pairwise(my_list),pairwise(my_list2),pairwise(my_list3)
```

that gives you **three** iterators of tuples, not one combined iterator of tuples. It doesn't combine the columns.

Here's one way to combine the columns:

```
def concat_columns(*row_lists):
    return (tuple(chain(*r)) for r in zip(*row_lists)
```

This uses `zip()` to create an iterator of tuples of tuples, and [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten each row. Your final code could then look something like this:

```
cursor.executemany(
    'INSERT INTO mytable(column1, column2, column3, column4, column4, column6) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    concat_columns(pairwise(my_list),pairwise(my_list2),pairwise(my_list3)))
```

Comment: for some reason when I do this the error is no longer there by my columns come up blank without any content.

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer whoops, I misunderstood your question. My answer won't work. Thank you for the edit that clarifies what you meant.

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer in particular, my comments about replacing `pairwise` with a simple `zip` were completely wrong.

Comment: I'm getting an error that chain is not defined in the concat_columns function

Comment: do I need to define the chain with a function like def chain(*iterables):

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer it's in `itertools` like I mentioned. `from itertools import chain`

Comment: how would I do this if the lists aren't all the same length?

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer what *do* you want to do if the lists aren't all the same length?

Comment: I basically want to be able to write a db that looks like this

Comment: well I can't write it in the comments but basically as it stands now the number of rows in my database is limited to the length of the smallest list. the rest of it gets cut off

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer the way you explained what you're doing in your question only makes sense to me if the lists have the same length. Maybe you could edit your question to explain what you want to do with the extra items in some of the lists?

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer also, if the items in the different lists aren't related to the other ones that are going in the same row (for example, if `my_list[4]`, `my_list[5]`, `my_list2[4]`, `my_list2[5]`, `my_list3[4]`, `my_list3[5]` aren't related to each other) then maybe there's a better way to organize your database? I ask because, if they *are* related to each other, then I don't see why the lists would be different lengths.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. Yes maybe I'm scraping movie information from a website and part of the information is stuff such as the domestic gross etc. There is also some tables that contain different charts and the movies ranking within the chart. I would like to be able to have a single table for each movie. the information looks something like this

Comment: 'Title = [Movie], Domestic_Gross = 1000000, Actors = [bob,jeff,alex] , Genre_Rankings = [Action,32,Comedy,41,Romance,12,Adventure, 61] ,Franchise = [First Movie ,12, Second Movie, 16]'

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer I doubt you can combine all of those into a meaningful 2D table. I think your next step might be to think about and research how you want to store your data. Some possibilities are creating an entire SQL schema, rather than a single table, or storing your data directly as JSON. It all depends on how you want to use the data after you store it.

Comment: @StanGetz Eventually I would like to be able to use the information for some form of predictive modeling, i.e.: using the data to determine what factors attribute mostly to a movies success and predicting said success off of these factors. I am a long way off and this is my first Data Science project but that is the end goal. So when you talk about the Schema I could organize it so it would have something like movie_title.title, movie_title.Genre_Rankings etc.. that way all of the information does not have to be in one single table?

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer right, by schema I meant multiple tables with relationships between them.